# Using SemaphoreSlim for divide execution for batches

Tags: c#, async-await, semaphore

I am learning asynchronous programming from scratch and have to solve one problem. Application which I am developing has to download data in loop per ID (around 800 loop pass). Each Loop pass get 10 to 500 rows from database and generating one txt file with rows. I'd like to do this asynchronously. Of course do not want to generate 800 reports at same time (800 sql queries) but would like to divide it to some batches. I use `SemaphoreSlim`:

```
public async void Generate(DateTime BusinessDate)
{
var throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(5);
                var allTasks = new List<Task>();
                foreach (var id in idsToGenerate)
                {
                    await throttler.WaitAsync();
                    allTasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
                    {          
                            GenerateReportForIdAsync(id, BusinessDate);
                    }));
                    throttler.Release();
                }
                
                await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
}

private Task GenerateReportForIdAsync(Id id, DateTime day)
        {
            return Task.Run(() => GenerateReportForOid(id, day));
        }


private void GenerateReportForId(Id id, DateTime day)
        {
            LogInformation(); // shortcut
            GetDataFromDB(); // shortcut
            CreateReportFromRecordFromDB(); // shortcut
            UpdateInformationInDBThatReportHasBeenGenerated(); // shortcut
        }
```

This code works so reports have been generated but it look like method `UpdateInformationInDBThatReportHasBeenGenerated()` has not been run for last 1-10 reports (depends on execution). So it look like application finished before execution of `UpdateInformationInDBThatReportHasBeenGenerated()` for some records.

Do you know why ?

**UPDATE**
This is working:

```
public void Generate(DateTime BusinessDate)
{
      var taskAsync = GenerateAsync(BusinessDate);
            Task.WaitAll(taskAsync);
}

private async Task GenerateAsync(DateTime BusinessDate)
{
    var ab = new ActionBlock<(Id id, DateTime businessDate)>(
        GenerateReportForId,
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5,
        }
    );
    
    foreach (var id in idsToGenerate)
    {
        ab.Post((id, BusinessDate));
    }
    
    ab.Complete();
    
    await ab.Completion;
}

private void GenerateReportForId((Id id, DateTime day) arg)
{
    LogInformation(); // shortcut
    GetDataFromDB(); // shortcut
    CreateReportFromRecordFromDB(); // shortcut
    UpdateInformationInDBThatReportHasBeenGenerated(); // shortcut
}
```

Comment: You're not awaiting the task from `GenerateReportForIdAsync` so the `Task.Run` in `allTasks.Add(...)` is immediately completed, I think. Try to await it and see where that gets you.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't change anything. I used: `await GenerateReportForIdAsync(id, BusinessDate);`

Comment: Asynchronous and parallel are not the same thing. And you probably don't want to be making 800 separate queries to the DB anyway. Make one query that gets all your data and split it client-side. Even if you do need so many queries, it's unlikely that parallelizing it will speed it up, unless it is very heavy on CPU and very light on IO

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I'd like to note something else: the `SemaphoreSlim` in your code is throttling nothing. To make it an effective throttler you should release it when a task completes, not immediately after starting a task.

Comment: Ah, now I see the problem. The `Generate` method is `async void` (which is [something to avoid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void)). My suggestion is to change the return type from `void` to `Task`, and `await` this task.

Comment: `I don't know the answer to your question, but I'd like to note something else: the SemaphoreSlim in your code is throttling nothing. To make it an effective throttler you should release it when a task completes, not immediately after starting a task` What is the most afficient way to do that ?:)

Comment: `await` the task in a `try` block, and release the semaphore in the `finally` block. It's quite efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that easily with an [ActionBlock<TInput> Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1) from [Dataflow (Task Parallel Library)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library):

```
public async Task Generate(DateTime BusinessDate)
{
    var ab = new ActionBlock<(Id id, DateTime businessDate)>(
        GenerateReportForId,
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5,
        }
    );
    
    foreach (var id in idsToGenerate)
    {
        ab.Post((id, BusinessDate));
    }
    
    ab.Complete();
    
    await ab.Completion;
}

private void GenerateReportForId((Id id, DateTime day) arg)
{
    LogInformation(); // shortcut
    GetDataFromDB(); // shortcut
    CreateReportFromRecordFromDB(); // shortcut
    UpdateInformationInDBThatReportHasBeenGenerated(); // shortcut
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Now have additional question. This solution is working but 2-5 times in generation process get IO error: `System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Test\[GeneratedFilePath]' because it is being used by another process.` Do you know maybe why I got this error ? Every Id has different value and different path for geneartion.

Comment: Are you sure the file is not open by another process or thread? Add logging when opening and closing the files.